# Dependency Problems after updating to 14.04?

Tags: dependencies, emacs

I can't seem to install or uninstall anything after updating to 14.04 because emacs and LaTeX was broken. I think I removed all the corrupt LaTeX files, but the emacs ones won't go away. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcanna1g
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  emacs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,624 B of archives.
After this operation, 25.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main emacs all 45.0ubuntu1 [1,624 B]
Fetched 1,624 B in 0s (45.3 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package emacs.
(Reading database ... 255502 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../emacs_45.0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking emacs (45.0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up emacsen-common (2.0.7) ...
Install emacsen-common for emacs23
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs23
/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/emacsen-common: 29: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/emacsen-common: emacs23: not found
ERROR: install script from emacsen-common package failed
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
      dpkg: error processing package emacsen-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs24-common:
 emacs24-common depends on emacsen-common (>= 1.4.10); however:
  Package emacsen-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package emacs24-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs24-bin-common:
 emacs24-bin-common depends on emacs24-common (= 24.3+1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package emacs24-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package emacs24-bin-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs24:
 emacs24 depends on emacs24-bin-common (= 24.3+1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package emacs24-bin-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package emacs24 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xemacs21-mule:
 xemacs21-mule depends on emacsen-common; however:
  Package emacsen-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-mule (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xemacs21:
 xemacs21 depends on xemacs21-mule (>= 21.4.22-4ubuntu3) | xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn (>= 21.4.22-4ubuntu3) | xemacs21-nomule (>= 21.4.22-4ubuntu3); however:
  Package xemacs21-mule is not configured yet.
  Package xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn is not installed.
  Package xemacs21-nomule is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xemacs21 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xemacs21-support:
 xemacs21-support depends on emacsen-common; however:
  Package emacsen-common is not configured yet.
 xemacs21-support depends on xemacs21 (= 21.4.22-4ubuntu3); however:
  Package xemacs21 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gettext-el:
 gettext-el depends on emacs24 | emacs23 | emacsen; however:
  Package emacs24 is not configured yet.
  Package emacs23 is not installed.
  Package emacsen is not installed.
  Package xemacs21-mule which provides emacsen is not configured yet.
  Package xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn which provides emacsen is not installed.
  Package emacs23 which provides emacsen is not installed.
  Package emacs24 which provides emacsen is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gettext-el (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs:
 emacs depends on emacs24 | emacs24-lucid | emacs24-nox; however:
  Package emacs24 is not configured yet.
  Package emacs24-lucid is not installed.
  Package emacs24-nox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package emacs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xemacs21-bin:
 xemacs21-bin depends on xemacs21-support (= 21.4.22-4ubuntu3); however:
  Package xemacs21-support is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xemacs21-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacsen-common
 emacs24-common
 emacs24-bin-common
 emacs24
 xemacs21-mule
 xemacs21
 xemacs21-support
 gettext-el
 emacs
 xemacs21-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try to purge the offending packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge emacsen-common emacs24-common emacs24-bin-common emacs24 xemacs21-mule xemacs21 xemacs21-support gettext-el emacs xemacs21-bin
```

Then, clean everything out before trying to add anything new.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Please post any errors.